# Send notifications on daily basis using FCM to the users with the message body from Firebase database data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a React Js, Firebase **BIRTHDAYS** web app which allows login using firebase. Users can add their friends birthdays in there. It will show the personalized list of birthdays.

So, Here I want to send notifications every day at some specific time for all the users using **Firebase Cloud Messaging**. And also the body of it should be different for every user and should contain the list of birthdays they are having that day(when the notification is sent) from Firebase Database. I tried a lot. But none of them worked. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Things I tried

1. Used only React to send notification. But the problem here is that we should not close the web app and for Mobiles `addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {})` is not working.

```js
let notification
let interval

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    let date = new Date()
    let dateNumber = date.getDate()
    let monthId = date.getMonth() + 1
    let hours = date.getHours()
    let minutes = date.getMinutes()
    if (hours === 0) {
      let requiredNames = []
      if (allBirthdays.length !== 0) {
        requiredNames = allBirthdays
          .filter((p) => p.monthId == monthId && p.day == dateNumber)
          .map((p) => {
            return `${p.name}`;
          })
      }
      notification = new Notification(`Today's Birthdays(${dateNumber}-${monthId})`, {
        body: `${requiredNames.length !== 0 ? requiredNames : "No Birthdays"}`,
        icon: logo,
        tag: "Same Time"
      })
    }
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      date = new Date()
      dateNumber = date.getDate()
      monthId = date.getMonth() + 1
      hours = date.getHours()
      minutes = date.getMinutes()
      if (hours === 0 && minutes < 15) {
        let requiredNames = []
        if (allBirthdays.length !== 0) {
          requiredNames = allBirthdays
            .filter((p) => p.monthId == monthId && p.day == dateNumber)
            .map((p) => {
              return `${p.name}`;
            })
        }
        notification = new Notification(`Today's Birthdays(${dateNumber}-${monthId})`, {
          body: `${requiredNames.length !== 0 ? requiredNames : "No Birthdays"}`,
          icon: logo,
          tag: "Next Interval"
        })
      }
    }, 900000);
  } else {
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval)
    if (notification) notification.close()
  }
})
```

2. I found some videos on it but all explain only till we Test push notification from firebase but not the real-time implementation.

Comment: "I tried a lot. But none of them worked." It's going to be really hard to help your concrete situation without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

FCM basically just a service that you can send message from server to client no matter app is in background or terminated. The server need to know which device you want to deliver.

The way can achive this is:

1. Register all users token to server
2. Setup a scheduled cloud functions for run once per day
3. Run query from rtdb to get which users friend today is his birthday, Also grab these users token then deliver message to device.